# Differnce between "numbers = [range(1, 11)]" and "numbers = list(range(1, 11))"

Tags: python

So I am following along with the Python Crash Course book online, and in one of the exercises it asks to create a list with the numbers 1 - 1 million. I tried to do that using the first method in the title, but that didn't work. After a while, I looked at the solutions, and saw that they used the second method in the title. I can't see where they mentioned the second method in the book, so I am a bit confused about the differences between the two. Sorry if this is a stupid question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the square bracket, it simply puts the object in the list

So

```
numbers = [range(1, 5)]
```

will give you a list of 1 element, which is the range object.

On the other hand,

```
numbers = list(range(1, 5))
numbers == [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`list` will iterate through the ranges and get the list of numbers and then put those numbers in a list

Comment: Ahh. I see. Thank you!